# ReactJS hook concise state tracking

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need a little help figuring out if there is a better way to implement ReactJS hooks without stepping all over while making the code concise. When all toggles are true a new div (BOX) will show up at the bottom of the screen.

**Is there a better way to track all State changes, or do I have to define each ReactJS hook individually?**

**Hooks:**

```
   // DEFINE
   const [enduringState, setEnduringState] = useState({
        checked: false,
   });

   const [directorApprovedState, setDirectorApproved] = useState({
        checked: false,
   });

    const [associatedConopState, setAssociatedConopState] = useState({
        checked: false,
    });

    const [displayPane, setDisplayPane] = useState({
        display: "none",
    });

    // HANDLERS
    const handleEnduringChange = (event) => {
        setEnduringState({
            checked: (enduringState.checked === false) ? true : false,
        });
    }

    const handleDirectorChange = (event) => {
        setDirectorApproved({
            checked: (directorApprovedState.checked === false) ? true : false,
        });
    }

    const handleConopChange = (event) => {
        setAssociatedConopState({
            checked: (associatedConopState.checked === false) ? true : false,
        });
    }
```

**Checking for change on toggle**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if ((enduringState.checked === true) 
        && (directorApprovedState.checked === true) 
        && ( associatedConopState.checked === true)){
            setDisplayPane({
                display: "block",
            })
        }else{
            setDisplayPane({
                display: "none",
            })
        }
    },[enduringState, directorApprovedState, associatedConopState]);
```

**HTML MaterialUI themed toggle:**

```
<FieldToggle
    toggleLabel={"Yes"}
    toggleId={"exceeds_100"}
    checked={enduringState.checked}
    handleChange={handleEnduringChange} >
 </FieldToggle>

 <FieldToggle
   toggleLabel={"Yes"}
   toggleId={"director_approved"}
   handleChange={handleDirectorChange}>
 </FieldToggle>

 <FieldToggle
     toggleLabel={"Yes"}
     toggleId={"associated_conop"}
     handleChange={handleConopChange}>
 </FieldToggle>
```

** Hidden Box only display when all toggles are true/checked **

```
<Box display={displayPane.display} m={1}>
// CONTENT GOES HERE
</Box>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch of options but the simplest is to smoosh all your checked states in to a single object and then update using an updater function for setting the state (doing that will trigger a re-render):

```
const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState({
    checkedEnduring: false,
    checkedDirectorApproved: false,
    checkedAssociatedConopState: false
});

const handleEnduringChange = (event) => ({
    setCheckedState(state=>({
        ...state,
        checkedEnduring: !state.checkedEnduring
    }));
}

// same for other setters
```

If it gets more complex you should consider other options such as `useReducer` or a state management library like redux but those aren't necessary for a few toggle states.

By the way, you don't need to use useEffect to track the state change, you can use the state directly to control the display property.

```
 const { checkedEnduring, checkedDirectorApproved, checkedAssociatedConopState} = checkedState
 const shouldDisplay = checkedEnduring && checkedDirectorApproved && checkedAssociatedConopState
 
 // ... //
 
 <Box display={shouldDisplay?'block':'none'} m={1}>
    // CONTENT GOES HERE
</Box>
```

Comment: Thank you. This problem was driving me crazy and I wasn't able to find code-samples to direct me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass some sort of name or id to the material components, you could do something like this as well:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  isEnduringChecked: false,
  isDirectorApprovedChecked: false,
  isAssociatedConopChecked: false,
});

const handleToggleChange = (event) => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [event.target.name]: !prevState[event.target.name]
  }));
}
```

Display:

```
{Object.values(state).every(item => item) && (
  <Box m={1}>
    // CONTENT GOES HERE
  </Box>
)}
```